# Convergence of Real Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the following real series:

$$g_k(x)= \left( \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}} \right ) \cos kx$$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Does the series converge pointwise or uniformly? Check the continuity of the limit in each case.

Comment: What have you done so far? Any thoughts? Also, are you sure it's $(-1^k)$ and not $(-1)^k$?

Comment: Thank you @5xum for the correction! I know $|coskx|\leq 1$. In addition, $|(-1)^k| \leq 1$. But these values change for different $k$, does this imply that $g_k(x)$ is pointwise convergent?

Comment: Is it the _sequence_ $\{g_k\}$ or the _series_ $\sum_{k=1}^\infty g_k$?

Answer (score 2):

$g_k(x)$ converges uniformly to zero on $(-\infty, +\infty)$ because 
 $\left( {-1} \right)^k \cos kx$ is bounded $\ge -1 \le +1$, and for any $\epsilon$ you can find $k$ such that $1/  \sqrt k \lt \epsilon$ for all $x$